# What's the way to get a access token with Guzzle having a working curl?

Tags: curl, guzzle

I have the following curl command (working):

```
curl https://[client_id]:[client_secret]@domain.tld/oauth/token \
    -X POST \
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_my_profile:blah manage_settings:cool"
```

How would I transform the call To obtain an access_token?

then how to invoke the following in a guzzle client method ?

```
$curl "https://domain.tld/products" \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer [my-access-token-retrieved-before]"
```

Answer (score -1):

Guzzle has [nice documentation with all the options described](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html), so you should try to write the code yourself first. And then, if something doesn't work, ask more detailed questions.